# Ethersjs - get ERC20 contract decimals

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js

I have the following:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { ws } from "../providers/node";
import abi from "../abi";

export default async (address: string) => {
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, ws);

    return {
        name: await tokenContract.name(),
        symbol: await tokenContract.symbol(),
        supply: await tokenContract.totalSupply(),
        decimals: await tokenContract.decimals(),
    };
};
```

abi is the standard erc20 abi found here: https://ethereumdev.io/abi-for-erc20-contract-on-ethereum/

```
{
    constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: "decimals",
    outputs: [
        {
            name: "",
            type: "uint8",
        },
    ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
},
```

all these calls are fine except the last one for the `decimals()` function.

I keep receiving the following error: `cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`

I have tried setting a gas limit on the call like so:

```
await tokenContract.decimals({
    gasLimit: "750000",
});
```

but this again results in the same error.

Is anyone able to advise as to why this might be failing?

The contract address that I query is a [valid ERC20 contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1800b081333A08bc5faAbb19a51dfCa15C1dfF21#code).

Comment: This depends on the token contract. Can you share the address of the token?

Comment: Also is the `decimals` function declared as a `view` function in your ABI definition?

Comment: It works for some contracts, for others it doesn't. Added the abi to the question.

Here is a contract it failed for: https://etherscan.io/address/0x1800b081333A08bc5faAbb19a51dfCa15C1dfF21

Answer (score 0):

In general `name`, `symbol` and `decimal` are optional methods according to [EIP-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20), therefore you should be prepared to handle that these methods error or return invalid data.

There are also contracts that implement this differently (e.g. by returning `bytes32` or triggering their fallback method), so if you want to be bulletproof you should add some checks to these calls.

an example for such a token contract is the "TheDAO" token: https://etherscan.io/address/0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413#code

Answer (score 0):

The contract you try to query ([0x1800b081333A08bc5faAbb19a51dfCa15C1dfF21](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1800b081333A08bc5faAbb19a51dfCa15C1dfF21#code)) was compiled with ABIEncoderV2, so maybe etherjs has some problem working with ABIV1 used to call ABIV2 compiled contracts.

The definition for decimals is slightly different with V2, but also with other fields so this does not explain why you have the error on decimals only, but just give a try to this ABIV2 generated directly from the source code:

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_wallet1",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "previousOwner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "_limitedbuys",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "account",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "decimals",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint8",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "subtractedValue",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "decreaseAllowance",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "dexPair",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "dexRouter",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "contract IDexRouter",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "spender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "addedValue",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "increaseAllowance",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "value",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "limitedbuys",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "owner",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "renounceOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "totalSupply",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "recipient",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "sender",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "recipient",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "wallet1",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

Comment: Same issue when using ABIV2 for some contracts. I'm using ABIV2 and if that fails falling back to ABIV1. In some cases both fail